# Vuejs: Refactoring Methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-router

i have a cuestion:

How would you recommend me to refactor a method?

I have a method that i use in some files and many times on single file too:

```
async getValidToken() {
  let jwt = await this.$store.dispatch('auth/getValidToken').then((response) => {
    if (response.jwt) {
      return response.jwt
    }
    this.$store.commit('ALERT', {
      color: 'error',
      text: response.msg + ', Please Login',
    })
    this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
    this.$router.push('/pages/login')
    return null
  })
  return jwt
},
```

It is important to mention that I create a store file for each case:

[image: files of store]

and import them into the index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as user from './modules/user.js'
import * as auth from './modules/auth.js'
import * as group from './modules/group'
import * as system from './modules/system'
import * as module from './modules/module'
```

I appreciate your advice in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export this function, in any file, make sure it gets the vue instance (since it wont have the propper "this"), and simply import it wherever needed...

```js
export const getValidToken = async (vm) => {
  let jwt = await vm.$store.dispatch('auth/getValidToken').then((response) => {
    if (response.jwt) {
      return response.jwt
    }
    vm.$store.commit('ALERT', {
      color: 'error',
      text: response.msg + ', Please Login',
    })
    vm.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
    vm.$router.push('/pages/login')
    return null
  })
  return jwt
};
```